# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') using useContext in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello i am getting error while using useContext in react.

error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state');

**problem is in about.js**

my app.js

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes ,Route,} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { About } from './components/About';
import NoteState from './context/notes/NoteState';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <NoteState>
      <About />
      </NoteState>
        <Router>
            <Navbar />
            {/* <LoadingBar
              color='#f11946'
              height={3}
              progress={progress}
            /> */}
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
              <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />}></Route>
            </Routes>
          </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

error is in About.js

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
//import NoteState from '../context/notes/NoteState';
import NoteContext from '../context/notes/noteContext';

export const About = () => {
  const a = useContext(NoteContext)
  useEffect(() => {
    a.update();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [])
  

  return (
    <div>my name is {a.state.name}</div>
  )
}
```

my note context.js where i created createContext

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const NoteContext = createContext();

export default NoteContext;
```

and finally my noteState.js where i useContext and pass the props

```
import NoteContext from "./noteContext";
import { useState } from "react";

const NoteState = (props)=> {
    const s1 = {
        "name": "Harry",
        "class": "5b"
    }
    const [state, setState] = useState(s1);
    const update = ()=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            setState({
                "name": "Larry",
                "class": "10b"
            })
        }, 1000);
    }
    return (
        <NoteContext.Provider value={{state:state, update:update}}>
            {props.children}
        </NoteContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default NoteState;
```

i am learning react.js from old course and i am thinking that might be the case that some functions are change in new React.js which is the issue

Comment: It looks like you wrap the first `<About>` in the NoteState, however the one in the router is not wrapped in a NoteState (`<Route exact path="/about" element={<About />}></Route>`). Therefore, my guess is that it doesn't have a provider and uses the default context (which is undefined in your case). Can you try to also wrap the router in a NoteState?

Comment: `NoteState` needs to include routes as children, that should sort it out

Comment: thanks man that worked... i was the one testing it to outside and change inside and forgot about app.js